# How to install ubuntu15.05 stand alone using UEFI mode and boot secure enable in lenovo flex 2?

Tags: system-installation, uefi, lenovo, secure-boot

I installed Ubuntu successfully using legacy mode but in UEFI mode I faced some problem. And Ubuntu boot loader asked me to create extra minimum 35MB space to EFI boot loader. I don’t know why? and what it does for?

I create EFI partition about 500MB but after completing install my Ubuntu boot loader showed same screen like press any key to continue but when I press any key to continue it happened again and again.

so, how to successfully install Ubuntu using UEFI mode?

Comment: How did you format your EFI partition? It should be FAT32.

Comment: I format it ex4. Ok I try it using ex4, then I will make a feedback. :)

Comment: You need to format it to FAT32, NOT ext4.

Comment: then what will be the mount point?

Comment: It is called `EFI Boot` or `/boot/EFI`. I do not remember. You will find it in drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

EFI partition should be formatted to FAT32, not ext4.

It is a common mistake.

Comment: It also needs boot flag if using parted or gparted to create it. Or if using gdisk it is code ef00. Actual code is a very long GUID that UEFI uses to know which partition is the ESP - efi system partition.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: boot flag is not needed for linux.

Comment: Boot flag not required only with BIOS installs. UEFI/gpt requires the ESP to be set and gparted uses  boot flag for that purpose. A few BIOS based systems have BIOS that checks for boot flag, so we still usually suggest one. But you are correct that grub does not use boot flag on BIOS systems.

Comment: I never set boot flag in UEFI.

Comment: Most EFIs ignore type codes, so the "boot flag" in parted may be unnecessary. Note "may be," though -- it's possible that some EFIs require it. It's also likely that some tools and OSes will become confused if the wrong type code is set. Thus, setting it is *strongly* recommended, especially if you're dual-booting (which increases the number of tools that might object to an incorrect type code).

Comment: This DOES provide answer to the question.